# Need help to correct my one way selection code

Tags: c++

Why when i enter totalprice>50 (42 pens & above), it wont execute the if statement?
Can someone help me? This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using  namespace std;

int main()
{
    int numbersOfPen;
    float totalPrice, total;
    cout<<"Enter numbers of pen:";
    cin>>numbersOfPen;
    totalPrice = 1.20 * numbersOfPen;
    
    if (totalPrice > 50)
    {
        totalPrice = totalPrice - (totalPrice * (30/100));
    }
    cout<<"Total price is RM"<<totalPrice;
     
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `30/100` is integer math, and will be 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a debug statement shows that the if statement is, indeed, executed. However, the `30/100`, as @1201ProgramAlarm pointed out, evaluates to 0. In C++, dividing two integers yields another integer, so 30/100 would round down to 0. That means nothing is subtracted so it seems like the if statement never runs. To fix this, rather than typing `30/100`, just use a float literal: `0.3f`. Putting it all together:

```
totalPrice = totalPrice - (totalPrice * 0.3f);
```

(As a side note, there is a shorthand way of typing the same statement as above using the `-=` operator)

```
totalPrice -= totalPrice * 0.3f;
```

Comment: `totalPrice *= 0.7f;` is even shorter